# JSON encode is not working properly with varchar

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I created an API for the Java desktop application because I want to get the data from an online database. The beginning was fine. But some parts were not shown as required. Below is how the data is in the database.

```
patient_id  patient_name    patient_nic patient_dob patient_note    
PTT00001    Rebecca J Burns 988249675V  1998-12-17  Had previously taken medicine for...    
PTT00002    Erica L Prom    926715648V  1992-06-21  To show up a second time for...
```

The PHP code I used to get this as JSON is as follows and it doesn't show any output(A blank page appeared)

**PHP Code :**

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "on_dam_sys");
    
    $response = array();
    
    if($con){
        
        $sql = "select * from patient";
        
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        if($result){

            header("Content-Type: JSON");

            $i = 0;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $response[$i]['patient_id'] = $row ['patient_id'];
                $response[$i]['patient_name'] = $row ['patient_name'];
                $response[$i]['patient_nic'] = $row ['patient_nic'];
                $response[$i]['patient_dob'] = $row ['patient_dob'];
                $response[$i]['patient_note'] = $row ['patient_note'];
                $i++;
            }

            echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        }
    }
?>
```

But when the patient_name is removed using the same code, everything except it appears as below. What is the reason for that?

PHP code 2 :

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "on_dam_sys");
    
    $response = array();
    
    if($con){
        
        $sql = "select * from patient";
        
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        if($result){

            header("Content-Type: JSON");

            $i = 0;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $response[$i]['patient_id'] = $row ['patient_id'];
                $response[$i]['patient_nic'] = $row ['patient_nic'];
                $response[$i]['patient_dob'] = $row ['patient_dob'];
                $response[$i]['patient_note'] = $row ['patient_note'];
                $i++;
            }

            echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        }
    }
?>
```

Output for PHP code 02 :

```
[
    {
        "patient_id": "PTT00001",
        "patient_nic": "988249675V",
        "patient_dob": "1998-12-17",
        "patient_note": "Had previously taken medicine for fever and still not cured. The body is lifeless."
    },
    {
        "patient_id": "PTT00002",
        "patient_nic": "926715648V",
        "patient_dob": "1992-06-21",
        "patient_note": "To show up a second time for heart disease. She is ready for surgery"
    }
]
```

**I also need to get the patient_name**

Comment: Maybe it's throwing an error? But you can reduce your code quite a bit by selected only the columns you need, and use [mysqli_fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to grab all of the rows.

Comment: `$response[] = $row;` is easier. No need to copy all single values manually and using index.

Comment: Unrelated: `Content-Type: JSON` should be `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 1):

Probably in one of the patient "name" there is some invalid char, in this case json_encode() simply return false, add JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR so the execution stop throwing an error.

```
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

Probably, adding also JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE will solve the problem.

Anyway, it is worth to find the offending row.